# How to avoid carelessly modify file installed by homebrew on MacOS

Tags: macos, homebrew

Because the brew always install packages into the directory

> /usr/local/Cellar

And it grants me full `rw` privileges, which makes me modify some files of the installed files by accident. I'm suffering from this pain.

I have tried to change its owner to `root`, but some packages fail to run.

For example:
While learning the OpenCV project, I do some practice. When I read its header file, sometimes I modify it by accident but I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it. 
According to the https://github.com/drduh/macOS-Security-and-Privacy-Guide#admin-and-standard-user-accounts

> It is considered a best practice by Apple and others (pdf) (p. 41–42) to use a separate standard account for day-to-day work and use the admin account for installations and system configuration.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so this question doesn’t appear as unanswered.